# Testing State changes in BLoC architecture

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs, bloc

I'm relatively new to testing and I can happily test UI components that use renders, but I'm struggling to figure out the correct way to test logic components in my current preferred architecture method.

I'm using the BLoC architecture method with RxJS as I much prefer using this to other state management libraries.

I've tried to simply import the functions or access them like I would do in the components and mock them but I can't seem to actually properly simulate the functions.

Here is the an example of the BLoC:

```
import { IHomeScreenService } from 'actions/interface'
import delivery from 'delivery'
import { ProtoBloc } from '../ProtoBloc'
import { IHomeScreenState } from './stateModel'


const defaultHomeScreenState: IHomeScreenState = {
  categoriesData: [],
  mealsData: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  mealsLoading: false,
  currentCategory: 'Beef'
}

class HomeScreenBloc extends ProtoBloc<IHomeScreenState> implements IHomeScreenService {
  constructor() {
    super(defaultHomeScreenState)
  }

  initialLoad = async () => {
    await this.getCategories()

    // Set a default category for initial load
    await this.getRecipesByCategory(this.state.currentCategory)
    this.setLoader()
  }

  getCategories = async () => {
    const { value, error } = await delivery.MealAPI.getCategories()
    const newState = { ...this.state }

    if (error) {
      console.warn('Request Failed')

      return
    }

    if (value) {
      newState.categoriesData = value.categories

      this.pushState(newState)
    }
  }

  getRecipesByCategory = async (category: string) => {
    const { value, error } = await delivery.MealAPI.getRecipesByCategory(category)
    const newState = { ...this.state }

    if (error) {
      console.warn('Request Failed')

      return
    }

    if (value) {
      newState.mealsData = value.meals
      newState.currentCategory = category
      this.pushState(newState)
    }
  }

  private setLoader = () => {
    this.pushState({
      ...this.state,
      isLoaded: true,
    })
  }
}

export default new HomeScreenBloc()
```

And here is my test file for this BLoC:

```
import React from 'react'
import HomeScreenBloc from './index'

let defaultState

HomeScreenBloc.getCategories = jest.fn()

beforeEach(() => {
  defaultState = {
    categoriesData: [],
    mealsData: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    mealsLoading: false,
    currentCategory: 'Beef'
  }
})

test('should get default state', () => {
  expect(HomeScreenBloc.defaultState).toEqual(defaultState)
})

test('it should set the categories state', () => {
  HomeScreenBloc.getCategories()
  const newState = HomeScreenBloc.getSubject()

  expect(HomeScreenBloc.getCategories).toBeCalled()

  console.log(newState)
})
```

Currently all tests are passing, but what I wan't to be able to check is too see if the state is changing as expected. I also don't wan't to test the API calls in this function as I'll be testing those in the delivery layer.

Any help is very much appreciated, I've been banging my head against this for a while and can't find any resources online that relate to this architecture method.